# File not found error in Jupyter lab using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I using online jupyterlab [which can be accessed through this link below if not then use the second link](https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/jupyterlab-jupyterlab-demo-gm5q55pp/lab)

[This is the second link](http://pyter.org/try)

So the problem is i have uploaded a .csv format file to the lab but when i try to load it using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv ('demo/big.csv')

print(df)
```

It gives me the following error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-56c1e19c9da6> in <module>
  1 #Task 1
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv ('demo/big.csv')
  3 
  4 print(df)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in 
parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, 
prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, 
skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, 
verbose, 
skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, 
iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, 
doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, 
warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
703 
704     parser_f.__name__ = name

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in 
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
427 
428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
430 
431     if chunksize or iterator:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, 
f, engine, **kwds)
893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
896 
897     def close(self):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in 
_make_engine(self, engine)
1120     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
1121         if engine == 'c':
-> 1122             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
1123         else:
1124             if engine == 'python':

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, 
src, **kwds)
1851         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
1852 
-> 1853         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
1854         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
1855 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'demo/big.csv' does not exist: b'demo/big.csv'
```

Please help me out did i gave the path incorrect or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should check and make sure that your notebook is in the same directory as the file you are trying to import. So if the notebook is in a folder on your desktop named "Notebooks" then place your data in that folder. Then, make sure that the

```
df = pd.read_csv ('demo/big.csv')
```

portion of your code only has the file name and .csv at the end. If the file is named big.csv then make it should be

```
df = pd.read_csv ('big.csv')
```

Those are the main reasons you would be getting that error.

Comment: I am using online jupyter lab the files are not in my local machine i uploaded it to the same directory where all the files are and that is demo directory but i still get the error don't know why

Comment: Can you download them from to your local machine or pull them from a github repo?

Comment: No its in my local machine but i uploaded it to the site https://jupyter.org/try where i work in jupyter lab can you please check that website and try uploading a file to it? it will solve the issue for you then you can tell me please

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you to try using JupyterNotebook instead of JupyterLab to workaround this file directory problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).